# query wordnet through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, nlp, wordnet

I am writing a web application which has to deal with some NLP issues.
I've written NLP apps before in Java, and I always relied on the JWNL library which is just what I need.
I wanted to know if, in your experience, there's a best way to query the WordNet DB from a webapp, possibly with an easy integration in the HTML+js framework.
I need to retrive simple informations about the words, like synset, hypernyms and similars.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The NodeJS/Javascript wordnet related projects for your reference:

- [Natural](https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural): General natural language (tokenizing, stemming (English, Russian, Spanish), classification, inflection, phonetics, tfidf, WordNet, jaro-winkler, Levenshtein distance, Dice's Coefficient) facilities for node.

  - [WNdb](https://github.com/moos/WNdb): the wordnet database for NodeJS(required via natural).
- [node-wordnet-magic](https://github.com/Planeshifter/node-wordnet-magic): The objective of this package is to make this richness available to the node eco-system. There are quite a few wordnet packages already, providing some nice features, but there is none that tries to reflect the complete WordNet architecture (centered around synsets). This is what the wordnet-magic module is aiming for.